# Mongoid querying DB while associating NEW unsaved records in a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, mongodb, many-to-many, mongoid

I have two Mongoid document classes in Rails with a N-N reference relationship, as below:

```
class Band
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  field :_id, type: String, default: ->{ name }  
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
end

class Tag
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  field :_id, type: String, default: ->{ name }  
  has_and_belongs_to_many :bands
end
```

Then I create new instances of each one and associate them:

```
2.0.0p247 :014 > band = Band.new(name: "beetles")
 => #<Band _id: beetles, name: "beetles", tag_ids: nil> 

2.0.0p247 :015 > tag = Tag.new(name: "rock")
 => #<Tag _id: rock, name: "rock", band_ids: nil> 

2.0.0p247 :016 > band.tags << tag
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} (1.3745ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 UPDATE       database=band_dev collection=bands selector={"_id"=>"beetles"} update={"$addToSet"=>{"tag_ids"=>{"$each"=>["rock"]}}} flags=[] (0.2341ms)
 => [#<Tag _id: rock, name: "rock", band_ids: ["beetles"]>]
```

Here a call is made to the database to update the driver class (in this case the "band"). The problem is that neither of these instances were saved and are brand new records!

```
2.0.0p247 :017 > band.new_record?
 => true 
2.0.0p247 :018 > tag.new_record?
 => true
```

So why to perform a db roundtrip for an unsaved document? Is there a setting where I can turn this off?

Version Info:

```
mongoid (4.0.0 80ed36f)

moped (1.5.1)
origin (1.1.0)

bson (1.8.6)
bson_ext (1.8.6)

rails (4.0.0)

OS: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]
```

Answer (score 0):

.new() method does not save it.

use .create() instead.

band=Band.new() does create a new **object** of Band class, but it does not persist.
When you push the relation using << method, the relation between those 2 new objects created.
So, when you query, those 2 objects are already in N-N relationship.
However, that is **object** living in this code execution , not really persisted as data. 
To save it in your mongodb, you need to define the first object with .create() instead of new().

It may look like

```
band=Band.create(name:"beetles")
band.tags << Tag.new(name:"rock")
```